# What is the preferred order for operands in boolean expressions?

Tags: boolean, conditional-operator

Is there any benefit to structuring boolean expressions like:

```
if (0 < x) { ... }
```

instead of

```
if (x > 0) { ... }
```

I have always used the second way, always putting the variable as the first operand and using whatever boolean operator makes sense, but lately I have read code that uses the first method, and after getting over the initial weirdness I am starting to like it a lot more.

Now I have started to write all my boolean expressions to only use `<` or `<=` even if this means the variable isn't the first operand, like the above example. To me it seems to increase readability, but that might just be me :)

What do other people think about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do whatever is most natural for whatever expression you are trying to compare.

If you're wondering about other operations (like `==`) there are previous topics comparing the orderings of operands for those comparisons (and the reasons why).

Comment: @sadboy: I found `x>0` more readable, somebody else may find `0<x` more readable, it's totally subjective on these simple expressions.

Comment: I just meant, like you say it is totally subjective so in whatever context or situation if something flows or reads clearer, go with that.

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly done to avoid the problem of using `=` instead of `==` in `if` conditions. To keep the consistency many people use the same for with other operators also. I do not see any problem in doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever 'reads' best.  One thing I'd point out is that if I'm testing to see if a value is within bounds, I try to write it so the bounds are on the 'outside' just like they might be in a mathematical expression:

So, to test that (0 < x <= 10):

```
 if ((0 < x) && (x <= 10)) { ... }
```

instead of

```
 if ((0 < x) && (10 >= x)) { ... }
```

or

```
 if ((x > 0) && (10 >= x)) { ... }
```

I find this pattern make is somewhat easier to follow the logic.

Answer (score 0):

An advantage for putting the number first is that it can prevent bug of using = when == is wanted.

```
if ( 0 == x ) // ok
if ( 0 = x )  //is a compiler error
```

compare to the subtle bug:

```
if ( x = 0 )  // assignment and not comparison. most likely a typo
```

Comment: Most compilers (e.g. `gcc -Wall`) should have a warning for `if (x = 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it's unusual to write expressions with the variable on the right-side, and as a direct consequence of that unusualness readability suffers. Coding conventions have intrinsic value merely by virtue of being conventions; people are used to code being written in particular standard ways, `x >= 0` being one example. Unnecessarily deviating from simple norms like these should be avoided without good cause.

The fact that you had to "get over the initial weirdness" should perhaps be a red flag.

I would not write `0 < x` just as I would not use Hungarian notation in Java. When in Rome, do as the Romans do. The Romans write `x >= 0`. No, it's not a huge deal, it just seems like an unnecessary little quirk.